# facebook app not redirecting when aurizing

Tags: facebook, api

When I first authorize a user it goes and stays on the Canvas URL(my site) instead of redirecting back to the Canvas Page on facebook.How can I make sure once the user authorizes they go to the Canvas Page?

```
$(function() {
  FB.init({ appId: 'myappid', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true, oauth: true });

  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
    if(!response.authResponse){
      top.location.href="http://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=myid&redirect_uri=http://mysite/myapp"
      }else{
        FB.api('/me',function(response){
        uname = response.name;
        userid = response.id;
        $.post("signin.php", { name:uname,id:userid},
              function(data) {


              });
           });
       }
   });
});
```

Comment: i have the same issue [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8207753/1053485


please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, change the `redirect_uri` value from: `http://mysite/myapp` to: `http://apps.facebook.com/appnamespace`

Comment: And it gives me an errorFirefox can't establish a connection to the server at www.mysite.com